# MySQL express constraint as calculated column?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints

```
Columns: id INT, provice_id INT, is_province BIT
Foreign key: province_id references City (id)
```

I'd like to express the concept: when `id == province_id` then `is_province == 1`. How can i express this? Maybe with a calculated column or another constraint?

**EDIT**: ok so many comments, i will explain why there is is_province attribute. I know it's redundant, but the table will hold about 8000 entries so the wast of space is not important at all. I'm adding is_province because (using DOctrine2) i can query for provinces more easly:

```
$provinces->findByIsProvince(true)
```

And yes, i'm mixing provinces and cities in one table, because a province *is* actually a city and share all attributes of it.

So my question is still, how can enforce constraint that `if (id == province_id) then is_province == 1`?

Comment: So you've combined cities and provinces in one table and you want to use a flag to differentiate the two? Any particular reason for this structure?

Comment: Yeah, @muistooshort is on to something. There might be room for improvement in your basic design.

Comment: @muistooshort yes, why do you think that this is wrong? See my edits...

Comment: Gremo, @mu_is_too_short means (I think): Why don't you have 2 tables, one for cities and one for provinces? The `province.id` would then be a `PRIMARY KEY` **and** a `FOREIGN KEY` to `city(id)` (as all provinces are cities too). Your `is_province` would then be just a search in the `province` table.

Comment: @ypercube thanks that would be a good solution (even i prefer to keep the `id` as an auto increment field and add a `city_id` attribute as foreign key in `province` table).

Comment: @ypercube has it right, you're putting two completely different things in one table and it all goes downhill from there. I don't understand your update either, provinces/states/... and cities are different things where I come from so it still looks like you're mashing two different things together.

Comment: I agree with @mu. You are using, too, 2 different names (province, city) which strongly suggests that these 2 are different things and thus need 2 tables. Perhaps there are occasions where a name is used for both a city and a province (like "Athens" in my country) but that's just an abuse. The city "Athens" is actually a different thing that the province "Athens".

Answer (score 3):

The information would be redundant if you stored it in the table additionally. It's a perfect candidate for a view.

```
CREATE TABLE my_tbl(id INT, provice_id INT);

CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT id, provice_id, (id = province_id) AS is_province
  FROM my_tbl;
```

That gives you `TRUE` / `FALSE` for `is_province`. If you want 1 / 0, then substitute:

```
CASE WHEN id = province_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_province
```

More on how to create views in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html).

Comment: But can you fake a CHECK constraint with a view and an FK? Or am I misinterpreting the question?

Comment: @muistooshort: I don't quite understand. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: I see "constraint" in the title and maybe I'm reading too much into it. I admit to being a bit confused by the question and the schema.

Comment: @muistooshort: my reading is that the terminology in title, body and tags is a bit off. If he knew all the correct terms, chances are he wouldn't be asking this question. So I offered my best guess, we'll see if it fits. :)

Comment: One potential problem with this answer (as well as fullpipe's) is that the `is_province` column in the view can't be indexed.  I'd sort of hoped that MySQL might be smart enough to use an index on `(province_id, id)` to optimize queries on it, but some testing suggests that the only effect of such an index is to convert a full table scan into a full index scan.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: an index on a binary column will only help, if the distribution is unbalanced. Else, a `WHERE is_province` will select a large part of all rows, resulting in a full table scan anyway. In PostgreSQL you could utilize a [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/indexes-partial.html) or an [index on an expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/indexes-expressional.html), that could improve certain queries. Correct me if I am wrong, but you can't do that in MySQL.

Comment: @Erwin: An unbalanced distribution is what I'd expect from the question; there are likely to be many more cities than provinces.

Answer (score 0):

may be your dont need is_province
your could just select provinces by add
`WHERE id = province_id`